# How to take apart this rear BMX hub?

Tags: repair, tools, freewheel, bmx, rear-wheel

As shown in the photo, what tool do I need to take this rear hub apart? I assume I need a tool which will fit in the 4 notches.

The problem I am trying to fix is that if you pedal, the rear cog spins but does not turn the rear wheel. Any pointers on that would be appreciated. I guess I will find out the problem when i see inside.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I doubt that taking the freewheel apart is a good idea, even if you can, since I dont remember seeing one that you can take apart and put back together. See my comment attached to Tha Riddla's post for more reasons to just get a new one.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. I will replace. I have posted a new question here: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/10133/how-to-determine-size-of-freewheel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a freewheel removal tool like the Park FR-6
http://www.parktool.com/product/freewheel-remover-FR-6

You can attach that to the freewheel and then use a wrench to remove the freewheel.

Comment: Freewheels, especially ones that dont have the brand name stamped into them, are not designed to last forever, and are priced to replace frequently. One similar to the one you have should cost less than $10. You SHOULD use the tool suggested above, but I have used screw drivers, monkey wrenches, anything that will push those internal notches. You can try soaking the freewheel in solvent if you want to save a few bucks, but the easiest thing is to replace it. (there are internal and external notches, if you get external, make sure there is enough clearance or you will catch on your frame)

Answer (score 3):

To follow up on Tha Riddla's answer:

If your freewheel is freewheeling in both directions, in all likelihood it is gummed up inside and the pawls are stuck open. (As a small note: the freewheel is separate from the hub and contains bearings, pawls, springs, and some lubricant.) You can either try to overhaul the freewheel or purchase a new one (they range from relatively inexpensive to bank-breaking). To replace the freewheel, you can either buy a freewheel remover or take it to a shop and ask them to replace it (the whole procedure should take 15 minutes).

Some freewheels are difficult to crack open, so the simplest (and cost effective) overhaul would be to drip a medium-weight oil onto the seam where the cogs and freewheel body meet. Be sure to thoroughly wipe off the area with a clean rag before you start. You can do this WITHOUT removing the freewheel and you should hear a difference immediately. Put the wheel over a rag and continue dripping oil and spinning the freewheel until clean oil comes out of the back side of the freewheel. This should loosen up the pawls and clear out the gunk inside.